# Trailing %20 white space in URLs producing 404 errors in Codeigniter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

Our URLs with a URL encoded trailing white space (`%20`) are producing a 404 error. The application is run on Codeigniter on Apache.

- `/directory/page%20` will return a 404 error
- `/directory/page` will return a 200 OK

How can I route all URLs with a trailing `%20` to the intended URL?

Comment: Just trim the URL before you URL encode it? It's better to fix the reason for an issue than acting on the symptom. The issue here is that there is an extra space, not that the router sees it as a different route.

Comment: The problem is that some third party websites are linking to us with trailing white space in the HREF.
Even still, I'm not sure where to add this function to effect the URL before you URL encode it through routing in CI.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that some third party websites are linking to us with trailing white space in the HREF

In that case you can add something like the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file to *redirect* (canonicalise) such requests to remove the trailing space.

For example, *before* the Codeigniter front-controller:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \s$
RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [R=302,L]
```

The "processed" URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* has already had the trailing slash removed, however, the `REQUEST_URI` server variable has not. So, we can check for the trailing space on the `REQUEST_URI` and simply redirect to "the same" (processed) URL-path, as captured by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

The `REQUEST_URI` server variable is already %-decoded. The `\s` shorthand character class matches against any whitespace character and the trailing `$` anchors this to the end of the URL-path.

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to make sure that it works OK before changing to a 301 (permanent) redirect.

Comment: Thanks MrWhite. I looked at your answer. The code returned a redirect loop. 

So I modified the answer and I used this: 'RewriteRule ^(.*)\s$ /$1 [R=301,L]'

Comment: Curious... What version of Apache are you using? And what other directives do you have in your `.htaccess` file? The code in my answer should not have resulted in a redirect loop (tested Apache 2.2 and 2.4). Maybe there was a conflict with existing directives? However, I would not have expected your suggested `RewriteRule` to have matched at all on Apache? (Are you using LiteSpeed perhaps?!)

Comment: I'm using Apache 2.4

I have about 25 other RewriteRules to redirect legacy URLs to the app's new URL structure. All are pretty straight forward e.g. RewriteRule ^package/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)-([0-9]+).(html|php)$ /deals/view/$1 [L,R=301]

Answer (score -1):

@Juan Cullen, this is a common issue when you have a space before a trailing slash. For example lets say: "http://example.com/directory/page /". you can notice the space before the trailing slash.

To solve this for all urls that have such behavior, you can use PHP's rtrim() function.

Check the code below

```
<?php

function fix_url($url) {
    $trailing_slash = ' /'; //notice a space before the slash
    return $url = rtrim($url, $trailing_slash);
}
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
$error_url = "http://example.com/directory/page /";

$correct_url = fix_url($error_url);
```

As you are using Codeigniter, you can put this function in a helper file and access wherever you want.

This is an Idea try it out and let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks. The example I give has no trailing slash.
Even still, I'm not sure where to add this function to effect the routing in CI.

Comment: @JuanCullen - If it doesn't have a trailing slash, try adding: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);` as the first line in your `index.php` (after the opening `<?php`, that is). That should remove any spaces before CI even boots.