# Remove whitespace in URL and make everything lowercase with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have whitespaces (i.e. %20) and Upppercase in my URLs that I need to remove with an htaccess rule

My web site allow to analyze Account Instagram analytics, so may happen that user wrote (as example) "kourtneykardash" , "kourtney kardash", or "Kourtney Kardash" to check report.

Url is resolved as:

```
https://www.EXAMPLE.com/report/kourtneykardash (correct version)
or
https://www.EXAMPLE.com/report/kourtney kardash (wrong version, with whitespace)
or
https://www.EXAMPLE.com/report/Kourtney Kardash (wrong version, with whitespace and uppercase)
```

All of three, of course, show the same report, but I would like to have only the exact version like for the Instagram account username, without any spaces or Uppercase characters. (this will solve too any canonical issue or duplicate contents issue..)

Actually my .htaccess is this:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=([\w/-]*)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /%1 [QSD,R=302,L]

Options All -Indexes

RewriteEngine On


RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml sitemap.php [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

How can I edit my .htaccess file to remove whitespace in URL and make every character lowercase?

Comment: Could you please do mention from which url to which url you want to redirect(serve in backend), please do mention it in your question.

Comment: See here: https://support.acquia.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007147373-Solutions-to-force-lowercase-URLs and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60339517/trailing-20-white-space-in-urls-producing-404-errors-in-codeigniter

Comment: Anyway, if you use PHP, there's a more simple solution...

Comment: _“may happen that user wrote”_ - you mean, users enter these URLs themselves all the time? (If not, and the enter the user name in some sort of backend to set the whole thing up, then you should perhaps rather fix it at that point.)

Comment: @CBroe Users have a search field, where they wrote the account name they want to check analytics. So, they can write "kourtneykardash" or "kourtney kardash", with the result I wrote in the first post. My question is: how to delete whitespace in URL? Uppercase is a minor issue to me, but whitespace is important to solve.

Comment: _“Users have a search field”_ - and what happens _after_ they type into that field? I am assuming that does not automagically redirect them to `/report/kourtneykardash`, but that you must have implemented that in code in some way in some place …?